# Annoying WiFi Issues with new MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi

I recently purchased a new MacBook Pro 13 inch 2017 model running on Mojave. I've had it for a couple of weeks now and it has worked fine, until few days ago when it started to present really annoying WiFi issues. Approximately once per day the WiFi just disconnects and refuses to connect for a period of time. It is resolved after I repeatedly restart the computer. It's not an issue with the router or the connection as all the other devices in this household, as well as my previous computer which had no network problems. Even the auxiliary shared network connection from my iPhone can be difficult to establish. Are network issues something characteristic to these models? Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

For "mysterious" wifi connection issues, I have a blanket method that I do with any client Mac that has them, and it solves the problem in about 80% of cases, and in the remaining 20% of cases it is hardware.

So try this: Go to the folder

```
/Library/Prefecrences/SystemConfiguration/
```

and remove the following files:

```
com.apple.airport.preferences.plist
com.apple.network.eapolclient.configuration.plist
com.apple.smb.server.plist
com.apple.wifi.message-tracer.plist NetworkInterfaces.plist
preferences.plist
```

You need admin to do this. Immediately after thrashing them, reboot. Removing these settings files will not 'mess' with your Mac in any, unless you have some very specific network setup you need to preserve, but doing so will in my experience solve many network hiccups.

If that doesn't help, one might suspect firmware or hardware problems.